# Is it possible to send push notification request from device to server?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification

currently i am thinking about using push notification service as an alternative to SMS in my applications.

What i need to do, is to send request (with data - e.g. user fills in text field on device, and request containing this text is sent to server via push notification service) from device to server. Server then processes this request, and sends back push notification (with some processed data) to original device.

So basically i am asking: is also device to server communication possible with push notification services?

Thank for your help.

Comment: Why using push? Why not just sending HTTP requests?

Comment: I posted my answer Matej. Good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested in comments, I've posted this as an answer

Why using push? Why not just sending HTTP requests?

Have a look at [`NSURLConnection`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [`NSURLConnectionDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDelegate) as these are probably the classes you'll want to use.

Answer (score 3):

Push notifications are only sent from server to device. You need to send data to your server, and the server sends push notification to the connected clients.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's interesting to comment the difference between PUSH and PULL:

The PUSH notification is the only way you have if you want your device to be *hearing* everytime for *news*, so the *news* can be *pushed* into it (explaining how this works would answer another question in fact). However, if your device connects to a server, which is in fact always *hearing*, info can be sent back as an answer.

Thus, when you want a communication between the server and the device, and assuming you really need this communication work with PUSH, what you should do is:

- Use PUSH to send data FROM SERVER TO DEVICE
- Use HTTP Requests to send data FROM DEVICE TO SERVER

Also you should have in mind that, everytime a HTTP Request is made, the server can provide an answer (and you could use for that JSON, XML, etc).

Comment: i am aware that http request can also provide an answer. With this in mind, if i need to send request to server in order to get answer (its always "request -> answer" communication model... not just answer) it is better approach to just use http requests, and avoid push notifications for this kind of communication... am i right?

Comment: Completely right. Just create a page on your server that is hearing to your requests. Make the request with your device sendind your personal request and, server side, process it and provide the answer you want. Finally, process the answer on the device.

Answer (score 2):

You're confused with the phrase "Push Notifications". Ultimately, it is a way for a server to send data to a device at any time this particular device is connected. You don't call a device-to-server message a push notification. James Webster is right - just use HTTP requests.